# How to change title at sidebar in Kibana?

Tags: kibana

I am new at Elastic Stack. I use Kibana 7.10.0 version and set up Kibana on Docker. I achieved to change navbar logo (sidebar top left logo), and now I have to change the "Elastic" title beside of logo. Since Kibana is a open-source tool, I think customizing something is not invalid move.

Which files should I modify for this issue?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file using vi or vim **/usr/share/kibana/src/core/target/public/core.entry.js**

locate Go to home page text like this
***/Go to home page text***
You can see the Elastic Text written next to the above mentioned text. Change it to what ever you want. build the file using npx gzip-cli -e=gz -e=br

finally restart kibana, clear the browser cache and see the changes.